# how to pass in f-string inside another string in dataframe series

Tags: python, pandas, string

How does one pass the number `6` defined as a string into `'text2=self.nmb'` where `self.nmb` is a method attribute

```
self.nmb='6'
X = pd.DataFrame({'A':['text1', 'text2=f'{self.nmb}'']})
print(X)
```

Desired output

```
           A
0      text1
1    text2=6
```

Comment: pd.DataFrame({'A':['text1', 'text2='+nmb]})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
In [1232]: nmb='6'

In [1235]: X = pd.DataFrame({'A':['text1', f'text2={nmb}']})

In [1236]: X
Out[1236]: 
         A
0    text1
1  text2=6
```

Comment: Hi. I forgot to mention it is inside a class/method

Comment: In place of `{nmb}`, use : `{self.nmb}`.